# Button display inline CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/47w0h73r/6/

```css
.one {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}
.two {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00f;
}
a,
button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

As you will notice, the button doesn't appear as `inline`. Why is this? How can I make this button `inline`, just like its sibling `a`?

#### Issue

By changing the `button` to an `a` you will notice that the `display: inline` makes the padding of the parent element to ignore the padding of both child elements, making them really display `inline`. The problem, is that the `button` tag doesn't really appear inline, which makes the parent element's padding push both elements down. How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be in-line with the `<a>` element in my browser (Chrome 39.x/Windows 8.1), in your linked demo.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, but I need it to `display: inline` ignoring the padding spacing, just like as if it was an `a`

Comment: same here, it seems inline

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question, and explain precisely what your demo is doing wrong, and what you want it to do. As to your explanation: "*I need it to `display: inline` ignoring the padding spacing, just like as if it was an `a`*" I don't know what you mean, since an `<a>` element doesn't '[ignore] padding'.

Comment: It is inline. Please specify the browser you are using.

Comment: Are you asking how you can make the two elements the same height?

Comment: if an element is `inline`, their padding is ignored by the surrounding elements. The `button` element doesn't do this. This means it is not really displaying as an `inline` element, its displaying as an `inline-block`. I need it to be displayed as an `inline`

Comment: It's not that a inline element's padding is ignored by its surrounding elements, it's that it doesn't contribute to the line-height. That's only for non-replaced inline elements, and not inline-block elements. See my answer for why buttons are always inline-block.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Trying to set a button to `display:inline` seems to cause some confusion. The inability to get `display:inline` behaviour is often attributed to it being a replaced element, but that is incorrect. `<button>` is not a replaced element.

In fact, [the HTML5 specification, Section 10.5.2 The button element](http://w3c.github.io/html/rendering.html#the-button-element-rendering) makes this requirement:

> When the button binding applies to a button element, the element is
> expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a button whose
> contents are the contents of the element.

The language is a little unusual, but the button binding does apply, and the effect is that the binding takes precedence over the specified value of the display property. The effect is that the button is always rendered as `display:inline-block`, no matter what its specified value is. There is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Add `line-height:17px;` to `a, button` and that should make them the same:

```css
.one {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}
.two {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00f;
}
a,
button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```