# Making a button type=submit look and wrap like an anchor

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I have a submit button on a form, which I would like to style and behave like an anchor.  I have tried to do this in css but you can see in my jsfiddle example, the button text is sitting in its own line. I can use anchor but want to avoid extra js, if possible.

HTML:

```
<span>blah </span> <button type="submit">blaajsdkla blaajsdklajsdkla bla ajsdklajsdkla blaajsdkla sdlaskjdas djakldaldasdjaskj aj as blaajsdkla blaajsdkla sdlaskjdas djakldaldasdjaskj aj as</button> <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span>
```

CSS:

```
button{
    border: none;
    white-space: normal;
    display:inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background:transparent;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    line-height:normal;
}
```

jsfiddle of the code
https://jsfiddle.net/zapjelly/30ta6ofm/4/

[Currently looks like and what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjJtg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi @MayankNimje - Sorry my question wasn't clear.  Have updated wording and included a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks!

Comment: This is interesting question, but few lines in js would solve problem more efficient than any css hacks and tricks, even if they are possible at all, in this case (IMHO). :)

Comment: Hi @nevermind - you are totally right :) but I thought someone out there might know of a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button display inline CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656634/button-display-inline-css)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of to render the button like a inline element. see

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-button-element-0

Buttons are always rendert as inline-block or block

Answer (score 0):

Use an input submit type, wrap it in a label, then give the input `display:none`. Although the submit is hidden, the label will act as a submit button because it's `for` attribute bonds itself to the submit. The label is an inline element. <kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/kpz5a1fn/2/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#dual {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 97vw;
  border: none;
  max-height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)repeat;
}
#dual * {
  border: none;
  display: table-row;
  font: inherit;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: .3px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
#sub1 {
  display: none;
}
label {
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #923;
  box-shadow: -8px 8px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<form id='dual' name='dual'>
  <label for='sub1'>
    <input id='sub1' type='submit' value=''>Blaajsdkla blaajsdklajsdkla blaajsdklajsdkla blaajsdkla sdlaskjdas Djakldaldasdjaskj Aj as blaajsdkla bBaajsdkla Ssdlaskjdas djakldaldasdjaskj aJ as Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne - Your answer does not address my question at all but thanks.  I would like the submit button text to not break into a new line away from the rest of the paragraph.  I could do this using an anchor but button type="submit" is better semantic, so I'm trying to fix that up.

Comment: At that length, you are either looking at it hidden halfway by the right side of the viewport or a tall element. You have described only what you are looking for but not what the result will look like. What are the dimensions? Is it okay to have it partially hidden? Do you want the text to wrap? Does it have to be 2 elements, because using one would be simple.

Comment: The update involves a label and input note the underline shows there are no line breaks and the layout is semantic and by the specs.

Comment: Hi @zer00ne - thanks for coming back and adding another comment. Screenshot I have attached might make things clearer in what I want the button to look like.

Answer (score 0):

One way this could work is by using `display: contents` in the button so as to make it seem the `container` isn't there, rendering the button's text on the same line your `span` text is rendering.

https://jsfiddle.net/5znfhoav/

Comment: This works visually, but will break the button behavior for keyboard users (you can't tab to it anymore) and is VERY BAD for accessibility.