# Button with ellipsis on a label, sized by parent

Tags: fluentui-react

Fluent UI PrimaryButton renders the `<button />` element.

This is a "replaced" element and it seems this cannot be changed with styling:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658723/1353203

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

I'd like to have a button which is "squashed" by parent's layout and doesn't change its size based on its content. Also, it would have ellipsis at the end if the text doesn't fit (instead of wrapping).

[image: the button working wrong - it wraps the long text]

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Danko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button `width` is based on its content or *parent element*. You need to modify some styles to achieve `ellipsis` content:

```js
<PrimaryButton
  ...
  styles={{
    textContainer: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    label: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    }
  }}
/>
```

Codepen working [example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/oNovaKa?editors=0010).

Useful links:

[MDN Text Overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

[Fluent UI Styling Guide](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling)